# convert an array of char into several String

Tags: java, arrays, string, java-8

I need to convert an array of char into several lines of a certain size. For example, considering this array :

```
char[] bases = new char[]{'a', 'c', 'c', 't', 'a', 'c', 'a', 't', 'a', 'c', 'c', 't', 'a', 'c', 'a', 't'};
```

the expected output would be for a size of **5**:

```
accta
catac
ctaca
```

I'm currently using this code :

```
    int ls = 5; 
    String str = ""; 
    for (int i = 1; i < bases.length; i++) {
        str += bases[i - 1];
        if (i%ls == 0) {
            str += '\n';
        }
    }
```

Is there some built-in function to achieve this in java 8? Is there a better way to solve this ?

Comment: A HTML element? This looks more like DNA.

Comment: I don't get how HTML is related to this.

Comment: `new String(bases, 0, 5)`, `new String(bases, 5, 10)` etc.

Comment: sorry forgot to update the title, should be better now

Comment: Several strings? Or a single string with a newline every 5 characters?

Comment: @AndyTurner single String with newlines, but several String in an array would be fine too

Comment: Side note: using `for (int i = 1; i < bases.length; i++) ` and `str += bases[i - 1];` you'd never use the last element, i.e. the hightes value for `i` would be 14 and `i - 1` would mean the hightest element you access is the 14th (at index 13).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert the `char[]` to string then you can use split with some regex like :

```
String s = String.valueOf(bases);//result = acctacatacctacat
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("(?<=\\G.{5})")));
```

If you want to make it in one line :

```
String[] spl = String.valueOf(bases).split("(?<=\\G.{5})");
```

**output**

```
[accta, catac, ctaca, t]
```

Answer (score 2):

Could probably utilize substring() to make it simpler. (Convert the char[] to string first)

```
 int ls = 5; 
 for (int i = ls; i < bases.length; i+=ls)
     someList.append(bases.substring((i-ls, i)));
```

Comment: Careful: this won't work quite if `bases.length % ls != 0`.

Comment: I believe it will still work, just won't get the remaining characters at the end of the string--which it was not specified in the question how to handle those--but his example just removes the ending characters.

Comment: If `ls == 5` and `bases.length <= 4`, using `i == ls` as the second parameter to substring would fail.

Comment: The for loop will not enter its first iteration if those conditions are set, because `5 < 4` will return false.

Comment: Ah, ok. So, you don't get an exception, you just miss out the last substring :)

Comment: Yes sir, which is what happened in his example, so I just rolled with it :) Always happy to dispute logic--no worries!

Answer (score 2):

You should pretty much never use string concatenation in a loop to build a string.

Use a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bases.length + (4 + bases.length) / 5);
for (int i = 0; i < bases.length; i += 5) {
  sb.append(bases, i, Math.min(5, bases.length - i));
  sb.append("\n");
}
String str = sb.toString();
```

Comment: @YCF_L ah, that third parameter is a length, not the end index. Thanks. (Confusingly, the third parameter in `append(CharSequence, int, int)` is an end index, not a length).

Answer (score 0):

Since in this case you have a very clear idea of the sequence you need to compose perhaps a custom code to create the corresponding `char[]` would be the most efficient:

```
   final int ls = 5;
   final char[] result = new char[bases.length + (bases.length + ls - 1) / ls]
   int nextIndex = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < bases.length; i += ls) {
      final int size = bases.length - i >= ls ? ls : bases.length - i;
      System.arraycopy(bases, i, result, nextIndex, size);
      nextIndex += size;
      result[nextIndex++] = '\n'; 
   }
   final String resultAsString = new String(result);
```

Comment: Note that this inserts the first newline after `bases[0]`, not after `bases[ls-1]`.

Comment: @AndyTurner oupps! your right thanks.

Comment: I have changed the code to use a custom solution perhaps more efficient than StringBuiler.

Answer (score 0):

This can be another solution to your question that is using the java8 Stream power: (for the sake of the comprehension I will leave the answer step by step, but a lot can be condensed and simplified/collected later )

```
int charsPerChunk = 5;
char[] myCharArray = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '+', 'X', 'o', 'c', 'e', '!' };
// turn the char array into a Stream of Characters
Stream<Character> myStreamOfCharacters = IntStream.range(0, myCharArray.length).mapToObj(i -> myCharArray[i]);
// collect that into a list of characters
List<Character> myListOfCharacters = myStreamOfCharacters.collect(Collectors.toList());

int size = myListOfCharacters.size();
int fullChunks = (size - 1) / charsPerChunk;
// get a stream of list of characters
Stream<List<Character>> result = IntStream
          .range(0, fullChunks + 1)
          .mapToObj( x -> myListOfCharacters.subList(x * charsPerChunk, x == fullChunks ? size : (x + 1) * charsPerChunk));

// print it
result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I think in this case the use of streams is overkill.

Comment: agree, specially this part....myStreamOfCharacters